# How can I make EasyPieChart plugin animate on scroll?

Tags: jquery, animation, charts

I made an animated pie chart using the Easy Pie Chart plugin, and I'm trying to get it to animate only when scroll position reaches 2000px.

I've tried some fixes suggested in other articles, but nothing is working for me. It was suggested to make the chart display none, then add a class at scroll position 2000 that makes it visible. But I found that the animation still fires on page load, the chart just appears already loaded on scroll.

Can someone help me? I'm a newbie to jquery and to this site, so my apologies if I'm doing something wrong :)

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li class="chart" data-percent="50"><div><span>50%</span>Completed</div></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
var options = {
  scaleColor: false,
  trackColor: 'rgba(255,255,255, .6)',
  barColor: '#2bb7e0',
  lineWidth: 12,
  lineCap: 'butt',
  size: 195
};

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var charts = [];
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.chart'),  function(el) {
    charts.push(new EasyPieChart(el, options));
  });
});
```